# Unable to override Spring Cloud Vault property Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config

I'm trying to integrate my Spring Boot app with Vault for loading secrets. The app runs on PCF environment so the main configuration file (application.properties) is configured appropriately. For local development, the vault authentication is done via a regular token. So I have created application-local.properties file with appropriate configuration for local development. Then I set the "Active Profiles" value to "local" under the run/debug configuration.

Problem is that when I try to start the app in IDEA, I get the following error. So it's clear that the vault related properties mentioned in application-local.properties are not being picked up during startup.

```
23:32:40.289 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${VAULT_ADDR}
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfiguration.createVaultEndpoint(VaultConfiguration.java:121)
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigDataLoader$ImperativeInfrastructure.<init>(VaultConfigDataLoader.java:445)
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigDataLoader.registerImperativeInfrastructure(VaultConfigDataLoader.java:177)
```

What am I missing here? I have copied both the application.properties and application-local.properties here for reference.

***application.properties***

```
spring.application.name=myvaultapp
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.main.web-application-type= reactive
spring.main.lazy-initialization= false
spring.profiles.group.dev=cloud
spring.profiles.group.qa=cloud
spring.profiles.group.uat=cloud
spring.profiles.group.prod=cloud
spring.config.import=optional:vault://
spring.cloud.vault.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.reactive.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.authentication= PCF
spring.cloud.vault.uri= ${VAULT_ADDR}
spring.cloud.vault.namespace= ${VAULT_NAMESPACE}
spring.cloud.vault.pcf.role= ${VAULT_CF_ROLE}
spring.cloud.vault.pcf.pcf-path= ${VAULT_CF_PATH}
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled= true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.backend= kv
spring.cloud.vault.kv.default-context=${spring.application.name}
```

***application-local.properties***

```
spring.application.name=myvaultapp
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.main.web-application-type= reactive
spring.main.lazy-initialization= false
spring.profiles.group.dev=cloud
spring.profiles.group.qa=cloud
spring.profiles.group.uat=cloud
spring.profiles.group.prod=cloud
spring.config.import=optional:vault://
spring.cloud.vault.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.reactive.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.authentication= token
spring.cloud.vault.token='Xxxxxxxxx'
spring.cloud.vault.uri= 'https://vault.myvault.org:8200'
spring.cloud.vault.namespace= 'apps'
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=https
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled= true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.backend= kv
spring.cloud.vault.kv.default-context=${spring.application.name}
spring.cloud.vault.kv.profiles=dev
```

***IDEA Run configuration***
[image]

Comment: We have the same issue. Did you ever manage to resolve?

Comment: for whatever reason, if I include all the properties in one file (i.e. multi document files), then the vault configuration from correct profile is being picked up. If I separate the values into profile specific files, then the main (application.properties) is being processed. I think this is an issue with property loading order but I didn't pursue further since multi document option (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#3-multi-document-files) is working for me.